# Can't RDP or ping GCE instance created from custom image

Tags: google-compute-engine

Newbie to GCE. I created an VM instance. I successfully RDP'd to the instance and successfully retrieved metadata. I then created an image from this instance. Then created a new instance from my image. But I can't ping or RDP into the new instance. I deleted everything and performed these steps again but still have the same problem.

This is a Windows instance. I know that Windows instances can take a while to start up. I tried for well over half an hour just in case.

Any ideas what might be wrong ?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found the issue. The problem occurred when I ran the standard sysprep command (windows\system32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe) to ready my disk for image creation. Once I tried **gcesysprep** instead, it worked. I found this command down in the snapshot help (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#create-snapshot-windows).